# wicked_pdf on Rails 4 not generating pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

My set up : Rails 4.1.1 and ruby 2.1.1p76 locally on MacOS X 10.10.1 and prod on Heroku.

I installed `gem 'wicked_pdf'`and `gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'`

In `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`, I added :

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

In `config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb`, I tried both :

```
 :exe_path => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
```

and

```
:exe_path => '#{Rails.root}/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
```

When I run in Terminal

```
$ wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf
```

from my app directory, it does generate a pdf file. So I assume wkhtmltopdf is set up properly.

My `object_controller.erb` contains :

```
def print_view
  @teams = [Team.find(params[:team_id])]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render :pdf         => "file_name",
             :layout      => "/layouts/print_layout.html.erb"
    end
  end
end
```

My `views/layouts/print_layout.html.erb` (shorten for clarity) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag('print', :media => :print) %>
  </head>
  <body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name%>">
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my `views/object/print_view.html.erb`  (shorten for clarity) :

```
<div id="schedule-tables">
    <%= render 'weekview_print' %>
</div>
```

I have 2 problems :

1. I get a html page, not a pdf
2. the page is using the default layout, not the specified layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should rename the view into `print_view.pdf.erb` as you allow both formats in the controller

And for getting the pdf you also have call the same url with the `.pdf` extension e.g
 `/objects/print_view.pdf`

Comment: I renamed my view to print_view.pdf.erb. Now I get `Missing partial shifts/_weekview_print`. Is it because I need to specify the pdf format in link_to (your second point) ? I tried `<%= link_to print_view_object_url(start_date: params[:start_date], team_id: team.id, :format => 'pdf'), :target => '_blank' do %>`. But my syntax is wrong...

Comment: Making progress. link_to syntax is OK. Problem was inherited partial was named weekview_print.html.erb; changed it to weekview_print.pdf.erb.

Comment: I ran into bad path error for wkhtmltopdf. Solution was to NOT configure path in wicked_pdf initializer.